# Is there a log of when a file times out its execution in PHP?

Tags: php, linux, logging, timeout

I have a PHP file that sometimes takes ~30 minutes to complete.  I have the server timeout set to 120 minutes, but because it can be so long I'm worried about spikes.

Is there a place I can see records of the PHP scripts which have timed out?  And what would that message look like, in case I need to search a large file (like error.log or access.log) for the timeout message?

I'm sure this has been asked/answered before, but I could not find it...

Comment: you can write output echo in the script and run by console(terminal) `php -f your_file.php` and you can see what doing on script

Comment: I have plenty of logging in the script.  My concern is that if the script times out, I can't THEN log "timed out" because the script is no longer running.  I have noticed the script started, but did not complete, for a few days.  With no code changes it completed successfully today, so I'm wondering WHY it didn't the past few days, and my logs are inconclusive.

Answer (score 1):

`php --info | grep error` should give you what you need like the error file location, if log_errors is on, etc